# how to make a cell with a hyperlinks formula become live after pasting

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, export-to-excel

I am pasting an Access export to Excel to another Excel Workbook. Everything is fine, except that a column filled with hyperlinks formulas (=hyperlinks("www.stackoverflow.com","My Name") are pasting dead.  I tried pasting all the data first, with PasteSpecial values,

```
    fromWS.Range(fromWS.Cells(2, 1), fromWS.Cells(fLastRow, FLastCol)).Copy
    Set toWS = toWB.Worksheets(WSheets(w))
    toWS.Cells(5, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

and then, grabbing the column that has the hyperlinks formula,

```
    fromWS.Range(fromWS.Cells(2, 123), fromWS.Cells(fLastRow, 123)).Copy
```

And pasting it to the final worksheet,

```
    toWS.Cells(5, 123).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

with the PasteSpecial formula option, but the column still has dead hyperlinks. (By dead I mean they display as text and when clicked on it, they don't go to the hyperlinks).

If I click on one of the cells, and hit F2+ENTER, the link becomes live in appearance and result. Thoughts? Help? would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

josé
PS: search around and there are a bunch of places where they show how to create the hyperlinks, but I already know this.  Again, thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0):

If someone knows a better answer, please post it.

In order to make the links workable, I had to run this piece of code after pasting the  data:

        `Dim col As Integer
        col = 5
        While toWS.Cells(col, 124) <> "" 'This has the ProjectID, if null EOD.
            If toWS.Cells(col, 123) <> "" Then
                toWS.Cells(col, 123).Formula = toWS.Cells(col, 123).Value
            End If
            col = col + 1
        Wend`

However, this is really annoying, as I my script is now much slower with this invention.  It should just work, after special pasting with the formula option. Thanks.

josé